# como impedir que un formulario se abra 2 veces

Tags: c#

```
Reparaciones frm = new Reparaciones();
frm.Show();
```

Así abro mis formulario ¿Cómo puedo validar si un formulario esta abierto y si esta abierto pasarlo al frente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui

[[WinForms] Verificar si el form esta abierto (instancia única)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2013/02/winforms-verificar-si-el-form-esta.html)

explico justamente esto que necesitas

Bsicamente debes buscar la instancia existentes en base al form para ver si esta instanciado

Por eso se usa

```
Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>()
```

para buscar si ya esta el form y pasarlo a primer plano

```
Form frm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x is Reparaciones);

if (frm != null)
{
    //si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
    frm.BringToFront();
    return;
}

//sino existe la instancia se crea una nueva
frm = new Reparaciones();
frm.Show();
```

si la instancia no existe lo instancias

Answer (score 1):

Tenes varias maneras de hacerlo, una, puede ser definir la variable frm a nivel clase, y luego, con el evento [`FormClosed`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Form.FormClosed);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), hacer un pequeño juego.

Por ejemplo.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    //Creo la variable..
    private Reparaciones frm;
    //En el método que pretendes manejarlo..
    private void MetodoEjemplo()
    {
        //Chequeas, si el formulario es nulo..
        if (frm == null)
        { 
            //En caso de serlo, creo una nueva instancia..
            frm = new Reparaciones();
            //y además, hago que, al cerrarse, la instancia frm se vuelva null
            //esto para que el if se cumpla, y prevenir un System.ObjectDisposedException
            frm.FormClosed += (o, args) => frm = null;
        }
        //Por último lo muestro..
        frm.Show();
        //y lo traigo al frente..
        frm.BringToFront();

    }
}
```

De este modo, deberías lograr lo que pretendes..

Answer (score 1):

Una forma seria declarar una variable fuera del metodo:

```
private Reparaciones frm;
```

y crear un metodo para crear al formulario, y meter algo similar a esto:

```
public Reparaciones GetForm()
        {
            if (frm== null)
            {
                frm= new Reparaciones();
            }
            return frm;
        }
```

Dentro del metodo que mandas mostrar el formulario dejar esto:

```
GetForm().Show();
```

Esto deberia funcionar si no me equivoco.